# How can i remove the Azure WebApp AppSetting WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, appsettings, azureportal

when I delete the AppSetting "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" in my Azure Webapp (Linux), it is there again after refreshing.

I can delete other AppSettings without problems, but this particular entry keeps coming back.

This is how I proceed. I delete the setting "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" via the trash can button, click on Save (then the entry is gone), then I click on Refresh and then the entry shows up again.

Has anyone had this problem and can help me?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Can you try clearing your browser cache a doing a hard refresh?

Comment: Btw, the Timezone for Linux Apps on Azure is managed via the [TZ](https://sajeetharan.com/2019/11/12/how-to-set-timezone-in-azure-app-service/) application setting.

Comment: I usually work with the Chrome browser. For this case, I installed the Firefox browser very fresh and tried it through it. The problem remains the same.

When I delete the setting and save it, I get the message "The web app settings have been updated successfully", but when I click "Refresh", the app setting is back.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Could you please try deleting this one via the command line? [az webapp config appsettings delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_delete) is the Azure CLI command.

Comment: P.S. You can use the [Azure Cloud Shell](https://shell.azure.com/bash) if you do not have Azure CLI installed on your machine.

Comment: Glad that helped! Summarized our discussion as an answer below. Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it benefits others in the community who run into similar issues. :)

Comment: Having the same issue on windows server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try deleting that specific app setting via the command line.

[az webapp config appsettings delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_delete) is the Azure CLI command:

```
az webapp config appsettings delete --name <your-webapp-name> --resource-group <resource-group> --setting-names <setting-names>
```

P.S.: You can use the [Azure Cloud Shell](https://shell.azure.com/bash) if you do not have Azure CLI installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" 
instead change it to a valid TZ table value.
For example "America/New_York"